# Scapy generating STP(Spanning Tree Protocol) packets

Tags: scapy

I am trying to generate STP packet and to capture it with wireshark.Basically what I do is  >>> send(STP()) from Scapy and the result from wireshark is:
53918   2671.938356000  00.00.00    00.00.00    FC  49  [Malformed Packet]
My question is how to configure the STP packet, the result from wireshark to be STP packet not FC.Please help :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the sendp() function instead of send(), and you also need to add the Ether() and LLC() layers before STP().  For instance:

```
sendp(Ether(dst="01:80:c2:00:00:00")/LLC()/STP(), iface=“eth0”)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `send` function is used to send packets in layer 3, while [`STP`](http://wiki.wireshark.org/STP) is a layer 2 protocol:

```
In [1]: from scapy.all import STP

In [2]: STP
Out[2]: scapy.layers.l2.STP
```

Therefore, you should use the `sendp` function.

See [`scapy`'s docs](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sending-packets) for further information:

> The `send()` function will send packets at layer 3. That is to say it will handle routing and layer 2 for you. The `sendp()` function will work at layer 2. It’s up to you to choose the right interface and the right link layer protocol.

The [official API documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf) states this as well:

> `send(pkts, inter=0, loop=0, verbose=None)`
>
> > Send packets at layer 3, using the `conf.L3socket` supersocket.
>
> `sendp(pkts, inter=0, loop=0, iface=None, iface hint=None, verbose=None)`
>
> > Send packets at layer 2 using the `conf.L2socket` supersocket.