# Sending hand-crafted BPDU (Spanning Tree Protocol packet) with Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ethernet, scapy

I'm trying to send hand-crafted BPDU TCN packets (and a few others that belong to different protocols) to test my network lab for DoS attacks.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827727/scapy-generating-stpspanning-tree-protocol-packets), but it doesn't help.

I've tried to use raw sockets and `scapy` but to no success.

This is my code using raw sockets:

```
from socket import *
from struct import pack
class EthFrame():
    def __init__(self, dst_addr='', src_addr='',  llc_header ='',  payload =''):
        self.dst_addr = dst_addr
        self.src_addr = src_addr
        self.llc_header = llc_header
        self.payload = payload
        self.header = pack('!s', self.dst_addr + self.src_addr + self.llc_header)  
        self.frame = pack('s',  self.header + self.payload)

    def sendFrame(self,  interface):
        s = socket(AF_PACKET,  SOCK_RAW)
        s.bind((interface, 0))
        s.send(self.frame)

p = EthFrame(b'\x01\x80\xC2\x00\x00\x00',  b'\x00'*6,  b'\x42\x42\x03',  b'\x00\x00\x00\x80')
p.sendFrame('eth0')
```

The result is a malformed packet containing just one byte - "00000010". 
As far as I read in documentation, NIC should add CRC and padding bits by itself.

And this is my `scapy` code:

```
import scapy.all
from scapy.all import *

netpacket = Raw('\x00\x00\x00\x80')
sendp(netpacket,  iface="eth0")
```

It also sends a malformed packet, this time containing two bytes.

The packet I'm trying to prepare is described at page 5 of [this pdf document](http://140.114.71.160/~cs4231/homework/hw3/BPDU.pdf).

I'm using Linux.

---- edit:
Following Oliver's suggestion, I'm adding information from linked document.

TCN (topology change notification) BPDU packet is layer 2, Ethernet(I) packet. There are minor differences in structure of BPDU packet, depending on hardware vendor. Here, in this example, I'm using CISCO implementation.

Ethernet header should always have destination address set to 01:80:C2:00:00:00 (STP multicast address).

Following Ethernet header, TCN BPDU should consist of:
Logical Link Control - 3 bytes, always set to [0x42, 0x42, 0x03]
BPDU header - 4 bytes, for TCN BPDU always set to [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80]

followed by padding (in this case 39 bytes set to 0x00)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you add the relevant pieces of information from that pdf document to your question? This is done to help future users, so that in case of link rot, they will still be able to infer what the content of the packets was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have forgotten the Ethernet length in your packet, between the source Ethernet address and the LLC. In your case it would be 7 (3 bytes for LLC, 4 bytes for STP). In your code, replace:

```
        self.header = pack('!s', self.dst_addr + self.src_addr + self.llc_header)  
        self.frame = pack('s',  self.header + self.payload)
```

By:

```
        self.header = self.dst_addr + self.src_addr + pack('>H', len(self.llc_header) + len(self.payload)) + self.llc_header
        self.frame = self.header + self.payload
```

But as suggested by @Yoel, your best option is to use Scapy:

```
>>> sendp(Dot3(dst="01:80:c2:00:00:00")/LLC()/STP(bpdutype=128))
```

Or, if you want to forge your own LLC level directly:

```
>>> sendp(Dot3(dst="01:80:c2:00:00:00")/LLC('\x42\x42\x03\x00\x00\x00\x80'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Scapy solution worked great.
Python script still sends just 1-byte malformed packed though.